# Adding time to date picker date and time results in same date and time. SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker, nsdate

I have a `datePicker`that I use to select a starting date and time, and a `durationTextLabel`to add minutes to that date and time. I set the `duration` to be minimum 30 if no text is inserted, but the value in
resulting date and time is identical.
Can you see where I'm mistaking?
Thank you very much as usual.

Here's the function:

```
func setQueryParameters() {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        var convertedDate: String!

        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd/hh/mm"
        convertedDate = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
        let calendar = Calendar.current

        let components = (calendar as NSCalendar).components([.year, .month, .day, .weekday, .hour, .minute] , from: datePicker.date)
        let year: Int = components.year!
        let month: Int = components.month!
        let day: Int = components.day!
        let weekday: Int = components.weekday!
        let hour: Int = components.hour!
        let minute: Int = components.minute!

        var duration: Double?
        duration = Double(durationTextField.text!)
        let endDate = datePicker.date.addingTimeInterval(duration!)
        let endComponents = (calendar as NSCalendar).components([.hour, .minute], from: endDate)
        let endHour: Int = endComponents.hour!
        let endMinute: Int = endComponents.minute!

        if durationTextField.text != nil {
            duration = Double(durationTextField.text!) ?? 30.00

        } else { return}

        // Opening Time Query parameter
        openingTimeQueryStart = Int("\(String(describing: weekday))"+"00"+"00")!
        openingTimeQueryEnd = Int("\(String(describing: weekday))"+"\(String(describing: hour))"+"\(String(describing: minute))")!
        print("opening query is \(openingTimeQueryEnd)")



        // Closing Time Query parameter
        closingTimeQueryStart = Int("\(String(describing: weekday))"+"\(String(endHour))"+"\(String(endMinute))")!
        closingTimeQueryEnd = Int("\(String(describing: weekday))"+"00"+"00")!


        print("closing time query is \(closingTimeQueryStart)")


        // Booking Query parameter
        let bookingQueryString = "\(String(describing: year))"+"\(String(describing: month))"+"\(String(describing: day))"+"\(String(describing: weekday))"+"\(String(describing: hour))"+"\(String(describing: minute))"+"\(String(endHour))"+"\(String(endMinute))"

        bookingQuery = Int(bookingQueryString)!// ?? openingTimeQuery  // found nil unwripping optional

    }
```

Comment: `hh` is wrong. It stands for 01-12 and it is normally used when displaying 12 hours  (AM/PM) format. For 24 hour format (00-23) you need to use `HH`

Comment: Which variable has the wrong value? What unit is `duration`? Seconds? Minutes?

Comment: note that you are adding only 30s and not displaying  the seconds. try `datePicker.date.addingTimeInterval(duration! * 60)`

Comment: @LeoDabus `duration` I changed into `var duration:TimeInterval?`and should be minutes. That should give me `closingTimeQueryStart`as 1830 if I select 18:00 in the date picker. but it doesn't.

Comment: TimeInterval it is just a typealias of Double and it is measured in seconds. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timeinterval

Comment: @LeoDabus yes, I wasn't adding minutes but seconds..
also I see that minutes get displayed only wit one digit as 1830 gives me 190 and I need it to be 1900..what should I change in the date format? I tried MM but to no difference.

Comment: MM it is not minutes it is MONTH with 2 digits

Comment: When displaying date to the user you should always use the dateformatter dateStyle and timeStyle so it gets properly localized. You should use a custom fixed date format only when parsing date strings.

Comment: so mm sohouldn't gives me minutes with two digits?
also I get a found nil error if I don't enter any value in the textfield..

Comment: Sure, I'm using this date just to create the values for Firebase Queries

Comment: Regarding the textfield you would need to subclass it to display only integers or double if you want to allow the user to add fraction of minutes.

Comment: If you want to store a date, you just need to store its timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate. No need to use strings.

Comment: I just use portions of the date to combine into a string for other uses, and I need the two digit minute

Comment: If you really need the custom date format just use something like this `"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm"`. Btw there no need to use `NSCalendar` at all. `Calendar` has all the necessary methods as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186667/discussion-between-vincenzo-and-leo-dabus).

Comment: can anyone see why HH and mm gives me onlyone digit each?

Comment: @vincenzo The only use you make of `dateFormatter` is to generate `convertedData` which you then never use. So your format is irrelevant.

Comment: @rmaddy yes, I just realised that, thank you very much for pointing it out, the thing is that I need not to loose 0s, say 9Am I need it to be 0900, same for minutes, 30 gets to be 3. how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many problems here.

1. You actually never make any use of `dateFormatter` other than creating and then never using `convertedDate`. So delete that unused code.
2. You have indicated at `duration` should be in minutes but you treat it as seconds. You need to multiply by 60 to convert it to minutes.
3. All of your code for calculating things such as `openingTimeQueryEnd` depend on each value being two digits but your code doesn't give the desired results.

For example, the line:

```
openingTimeQueryEnd = Int("\(String(describing: weekday))"+"\(String(describing: hour))"+"\(String(describing: minute))")!
```

should be rewritten as:

```
openingTimeQueryEnd = Int(String(format: "%02d%02d%02d", weekday, hour, minute))!
```

or as:

```
openingTimeQueryEnd = weekday * 10000 + hour * 100 + minute
```

Make similar changes to the other similar lines.

Comment: Many thanks, the formatting directly on the parameter is just what I was looking for. I realised after a while that I wasn't making use of the `dateFormatter` , I have a lot to learn still, and thanks to you guys I have been able to achieve a lot. So thankful to be part of this community .